# React: Skip row if json parent tag don't exist

Tags: json, reactjs

I am in the following situation and have the following problems.

I am developing an application that reads data from a .json file. I store this data in rows. Now the .json files can be different and therefore I have to cover every case (there are many cases). If a tag is not present in the .json, this row should not be displayed.

Now it can happen that I have covered a case which searches for `data.test.person` but `data.test` is not present in the JSON.

A case could look like this:

```
<TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt
         title={"Test"}
         value={data.test}>


         <TestAntragsdatenRow
                label1={"Person"}
                value1={data.test.person}
         />

</TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt>
```

This is my component.

```
export default class TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt extends React.Component {

    value;
    title;

    render() {
        this.value = this.props.value;
        this.title = this.props.title;

        return (
            <>
                <h4 className={"antragsdatenAbschnitt"}>
                    {checkAbschnitt(this.title, this.value)}
                </h4>
                {this.value != null &&
                    this.props.children
                }
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

With the query `this.value != null &&` I have tried to work around the error.

The error I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'person' of undefined`

My question now is, how can I query JSON tags if they exist, if so the rows should be checked. If not all rows with this tag should be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(data).includes('test')`
can be a way of checking if json object has the property.

There are a lot of other ways as well. You can also try:

`value1={data.test ? data.test.person : 'error'}`
kind of approach for safe null-checking

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, but let's try to unpack everything:

You're passing two props, `title` and `value` to your component named `TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt`. This you should receive in props, and therefore there's no need for you to store them in fields (`this.value = this.props.value`) for example.

Rather, just do this in the render function:
`const {title, value, children} = this.props;`

And now you don't need to use `this.title` and `this.value`, but just `title` and `value`.

OK we got that out of the way, now let's figure out why your optional key isn't working:

Now you should be rendering your children like this:

```js
{children}
```

Now you need to conditionally render particular rows, and this shouldn't be done here in this component at all. This should be done in the component that's rendering `TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt` (first component you wrote in the post).

So you'd do something like this:

```js
<TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt
  title={"Test"}
  value={data.test}>

  {data && data.test && data.test.person ? (
    <TestAntragsdatenRow
      label1={"Person"}
      value1={data.test.person}
    />
  ) : (
    <p>data.test.person is not valid</p>
  )}
</TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt>
```

As you can see, I check with the ternary operator if `data.test.person` is not null, if it isn't then just render the row, if not then just do something else you'd like.

You could do this in other component, but this way it's way cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and helpful answer. I will still try it out. What I wanted to ask is if the query in the last section is necessary. The query for ```data.test.person``` is already done in the component ```TestAntragsdatenRow```. What I actually wanted to achieve is a general query in the component ```TestAntragsdatenAbschnitt``` because your solution is very time-consuming for me because I have to cover a lot of cases.

Comment: There's a quick way to check this too: `data?.test?.person`. Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: It will give you `undefined` if it doesn't exist. And the real value if it exists.